# Extract, zip and publish TFS source-controlled items to FTP server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

I want to publish nightly builds + source code of a specific project on a tfs 2010 server (local network, inside the firewall) to a (local network, in the dmz) ftp server.

- Build
- Get latest version
- Zip build and code
- Copy to ftp server

Copying the files can use ftp protocol or copy to network share.

Can I do this easily with team-build, or do I need extra tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using Team Foundation Build. There are even zip and ftp Activities that ship with VS and are ready to use.

If you want a tool to make it easyer then I would recommend [Final Builder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/). This tool inegrates into Team Foundation Build with an Activity that runs after Build and Test that you can do pretty much anything in. It has FTP and Zip Activities ready for dragging and dropping.

Comment: the zip and ftp copy tasks ship as part of team build 2010?

Comment: Thanks @StephaneT, I have updated the copy to reflect your responce.

Comment: @MrHinsh, where exactly are these activities for zip and ftp? I have VS2010 Ultimate, and I can't find them.

Comment: I'm also having no luck finding these activities?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complicated as we had, like synchronize/cleanup a remote site via FTP, you can easily create your custom CodeActivity and do FTP via `WebClient` directly in C# code.